# OnConnect Sport Listing data

Tags: gracenote

I recently created an application for the Gracenote OnConnect platform specifically to query Sport tv listings data. My project is an open source tool to allow users to easily find the channel for a given search event. So for example, if I wanted to find out when and on what channel the Yankees vs Red Sox game was tonight, I would go this site, search "Yankees vs Red Sox" and see that it is on ESPN at 7pm.

I've received an API key from the OnConnect API on the "Public Plan" and have made a few calls. It seems as though some of the required data is there, but I wanted to get some feedback before getting into the weeds. First of all, could I use the available API using the free public plan to get this kind of data? If so, do you have any suggestions for how to work with the API including specific endpoints to hit or consumption patterns?

Thank you,

Vance Faulkner

Answer (score 0):

OnConnect API Public Plan is only for you to try out and test internally. Therefore, you cannot use it in your open source tool.